# Can we have user accounts on aa android mobile phone as we have for user operating systems

Tags: android, file-permissions, user-accounts

I just want to create a program which runs on start up which0 will ask to login with a username and password .

Once he logs in he should be able to access the files only which he is authorised to(for which he is having the permissions) .?

can any one tell me if its possible on an android phone.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: It's possible with some extended modifications of the Android OS. Unfortunately, you will be able to do those modifications to the Android Open Source Project code base, which means you'll lose access to most of the Google Apps and the Market.

Explanation:

While the underlying Linux supports different users with the proper file permissions, Android has chosen to use that support for apps isolation. For each application on the phone a separate Linux user is created and assigned, and the files that the application creates are properly permissioned only for that user id.

Thus, if you want to introduce real user accounts switching, you will have to either:
 - change the way the app isolation works - way too much work, and big security risk;
 - have two separate user ids (one for each real user account) created for each application and change the ActivityManager to assign the right one when it starts the application process. Again, way too much work.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a custom launcher that would ask you for a username and password, but you can't (on a stock android system) create a system username and password.

Comment: cant i pop up an intent (whenever  i try to open a file )which will ask the user to enter a username and password and to continue opening a file only if the username and password are valid.

Comment: Not on a default stock android device, no.